# Spring security + hibernate + rest (Context initialization failed)

Tags: spring-mvc, spring, безопасность, hibernate

Добрый день! Начал разбираться со spring. Не получается подключить security.

Получаю ошибку:

```
30-Sep-2014 12:41:21.317 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private test.service.CustomUserDetailsService test.init.SecurityConfig.customUserDetailsService; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set test.service.CustomUserDetailsService field test.init.SecurityConfig.customUserDetailsService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4736)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5158)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:702)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:697)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1646)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:413)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private test.service.CustomUserDetailsService test.init.SecurityConfig.customUserDetailsService; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set test.service.CustomUserDetailsService field test.init.SecurityConfig.customUserDetailsService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set test.service.CustomUserDetailsService field test.init.SecurityConfig.customUserDetailsService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:741)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:504)
    ... 58 more
```

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@ComponentScan( basePackages = "test.service" )
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("restAuthenticationEntryPoint")
    private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private MySavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler mySuccessHandler;

    protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN")
                .and()
                .formLogin().usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").successHandler(mySuccessHandler)
                .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint);

    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

**CustomUserDetailsService**

```
@Service("customUserDetailsService")
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        test.model.hibernate.User domainUser = userDAO.findByUserName(login);

        boolean enabled = true;
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;

        return new User(
                domainUser.getLogin(),
                domainUser.getPassword(),
                enabled,
                accountNonExpired,
                credentialsNonExpired,
                accountNonLocked,
                getAuthorities(domainUser.getRole().getId())
        );
    }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Integer role) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authList = getGrantedAuthorities(getRoles(role));
        return authList;
    }

    public List<String> getRoles(Integer role) {

        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (role.intValue() == 1) {
            roles.add("ROLE_MODERATOR");
            roles.add("ROLE_ADMIN");
        } else if (role.intValue() == 2) {
            roles.add("ROLE_MODERATOR");
        }
        return roles;
    }

    public static List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> roles) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        for (String role : roles) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
        }
        return authorities;
    }

}
```

**UserServiceImpl**

```
@Service("userServiceImpl")
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    public User getUser(String login) {
        return userDAO.getUser(login);
    }

}

public interface UserService {
    public User getUser(String login);
}
```

**MySavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler**

```
public class MySavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler
        extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private RequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                        Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
        SavedRequest savedRequest = requestCache.getRequest(request, response);

        if (savedRequest == null) {
            clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
            return;
        }
        String targetUrlParam = getTargetUrlParameter();
        if (isAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl() ||
                (targetUrlParam != null &&
                        StringUtils.hasText(request.getParameter(targetUrlParam)))) {
            requestCache.removeRequest(request, response);
            clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
            return;
        }

        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
    }

    public void setRequestCache(RequestCache requestCache) {
        this.requestCache = requestCache;
    }
}

@Component( "restAuthenticationEntryPoint" )
public class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                          AuthenticationException authException ) throws IOException {
        response.sendError( HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized" );
    }
}
```

**RootConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("test")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class RootConfig {
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";
    @Resource
    private Environment env;
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));
        return dataSource;
    }
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibProperties());
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }
    private Properties hibProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        return properties;
    }
    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поторопился я с ответом, пересмотрел код ваш, попробуйте вот так

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
```

Comment: Поправил ответ свой, более детально ваш код посмотрел, нужно вместо CustomUserDetailsService писать интерфейс UserDetailsService, инициализацию Bean убирайте, потому что он у вас уже объявлен как сервис.

Comment: Поменял на UserDetailsService, теперь CustomUserDetailsService не используется!? Но деплоиться начал!

Comment: Как это не используется? Вы понимаете, что такое DI и для чего нужны аннотации @Autowired и @Qualifier ?